# Windows Phone Back button and page instance creation

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I need to recreate new page instance on every page load (also when user pressed Back button).
So I overrided `OnBackKeyPress` method:

```
protected override void OnBackKeyPress(CancelEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnBackKeyPress(e);
    if (NavigationService.CanGoBack) {
        e.Cancel = true;
        var j = NavigationService.RemoveBackEntry();
        NavigationService.Navigate(j.Source);
        NavigationService.RemoveBackEntry();
    }
}
```

The problem is that I can't handle case when user press back button to close `CustomMessageBox` dialog. How can I check it? Or is there any way to force recreation of page instance when going back through history state?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you need to recreate the page instance?  If you are simply trying to re-read the data to be displayed, why not put the data loading logic into OnNavigatedTo()?

Assuming that is what you are actually trying to achieve, try something like this...

```
public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
{
    // Constructor
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        // don't do your data loading here.  This will only be called on page creation.
    }

    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        LoadData();
        base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
    }

    MyViewModel model;

    async void LoadData()
    {
        model = new MyViewModel();
        await model.LoadDataAsync();
    }
}
```

If you also have specific logic that you need to run on first construction of the page vs. on a back key navigation, check the NavigationMode property of the NavigationEventArgs object that gets passed to OnNavigatedTo.

```
if(e.NavigationMode == NavigationMode.New)
{
    //do what you need to do specifically for a new page instance
}
if (e.NavigationMode == NavigationMode.Back)
{
    // do anything specific for back navigation here.
}
```

Comment: Yep, I thinked again about logic, and understood, that I need to separate data initialization and data reload. My decision about overriding `OnBackKeyPress` was fast and bad. Now I init all in page constructor (is it the same as `NavigationMode.New`?) and reinit it on `OnNavigatedTo`.

Answer (score 0):

Ha, [in the near thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows-phone-7), i have opposite question :)

What about MessageBox - it depends, which one are you using. It can be [custom message box](http://visuallylocated.com/post/2011/11/13/Creating-a-Custom-MessageBox-for-Windows-Phone-Applications.aspx), for example. Anyway, try to check MessageBox.IsOpened (or alternative for your MessageBox) in your OnBackKeyPress().

Another solution is to use OnNavigatedTo() of the page you want to be new each time.

Third solution: in case you works with Mvvm Light, add some unique id in ViewModel getter, like

```
public MyViewModel MyViewModel
    {
        get
        {
            return ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<MyViewModel>((++Uid).ToString());
        }
    }
```

This would force to recreate new ViewModel each time, so you'd have different instance of VM, so you would have another data on the View.